# Selenium RC gives Error-Object [object HTMLIFrameElement] has no method 'getCurrentWindow' while running the test in Google Chrome

Tags: selenium, testing, automation, selenium-rc

I am using Selenium RC and Chrome when I run the test it gives me this error

```
error(1340708572726): Unexpected Exception: Object [object HTMLIFrameElement] has no method 'getCurrentWindow'
```

However I am not always getting this error. Some times the test passes and sometime the very test fails. I changed the Browser to IE and was not getting this error.
Here is the relevant part of the code

```
void editResumeInfo(String objective, String company, String jobDesc, String city, String phoneCountry, String phoneArea, String phoneNumb, String coleg, String certificateName, String certificateLocation, String seminarName, String seminarLocation, String notes){
        selenium.type("id=objective", objective)
        selenium.click("xpath=//html/body/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[3]/form/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/a")
        selenium.select("id=experienceIndustry0", "label=Health Care")
        selenium.select("name=experienceProfession", "label=Direct Support Professional")
        selenium.select("id=experienceStartDate0_month", "label=May")
        selenium.select("id=experienceStartDate0_year", "label=2006")
        selenium.select("id=experienceEndDate0_month", "label=August")
        selenium.select("id=experienceEndDate0_year", "label=2011")
        selenium.type("id=experienceCompany0", company)
        selenium.type("id=experienceJobDesc0", jobDesc)
        selenium.type("id=experienceAddressCity0", city)
        selenium.select("id=experienceAddressCountry0", "label=Guyana")
        selenium.type("id=experiencePhoneCountryCode0", phoneCountry)
        selenium.type("id=experienceAreaCode0", phoneArea)
        selenium.type("id=experiencePhoneNumber0", phoneNumb)
        
        selenium.click("xpath=//html/body/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[3]/form/div/div/div[3]/div[3]/a")
        selenium.select("id=educationLevel0", "label=Post Graduate")
        selenium.select("id=educationDegree0", "label=Biomedical Science")
        selenium.type("id=educationCollege0", coleg)
        selenium.select("id=educationGradDate0_year", "label=2011")
        selenium.type("id=certificateName0", certificateName)
        selenium.type("id=certificateLocation0", certificateLocation)
        selenium.select("id=certificateDate0_month", "label=May")
        selenium.select("id=certificateDate0_year", "label=2004")
        
        selenium.click("xpath=//html/body/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[3]/form/div/div/div[4]/div[3]/a")
        selenium.type("id=seminarName0", seminarName)
        selenium.type("id=seminarLocation0", seminarLocation)
        selenium.select("name=seminarDate_month", "label=March")
        selenium.select("name=seminarDate_year", "label=2011")
        selenium.type("id=skillNotes", notes)
        selenium.clickAndWait("id=submit")
    }
```

I am calling this method from

```
@Test
    void objectiveFiveThousandInputShowSuccess(){
        values=TestDataController.characterGen(5000)
        editResumeInfo(values, "abcd", "this is job", "bangalore", "91", "0381", "232269876", "IIT", "test certificate", "bangalore", "test seminar", "delhi", "note" )
        CheckSuccess()
    }
    
    @Test
    void objectiveFieldOnNullInputShowSuccess(){
        editResumeInfo("", "abcd", "this is job", "bangalore", "91", "0381", "232698376", "IIT", "test certificate", "bangalore", "test seminar", "delhi", "note" )
        CheckSuccess()
    }
    
    @Test
    void companyFieldOnFiveHundredShowSuccess(){
        values=TestDataController.characterGen(500)
        editResumeInfo("objective", values, "this is job", "bangalore", "91", "0381", "23269876", "IIT", "test certificate", "bangalore", "test seminar", "delhi", "note" )
        CheckSuccess()
    }
```

Comment: after some research.. all i could found out that to solve this error one have to work around with diffrerent wait commands eg:- openAndWait, waitForElementPresent, etc...

Comment: Apparenly this problem is a known issue with Google Chrome, see also [this bug report](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=653)